Existence of absolutely convergent subseries given the base sequence converges to zero
My Real Analysis final is coming up and I'd like to practice working with sequences and series, so I picked a practice problem and tried working it out. The statement is the following:

Let $ (x_n)_n $ be a sequence of complex numbers which converges to zero. Does there always exist a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k $ such that $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_{n_k}$ converges absolutely? Give a proof or a counterexample.

My (admittedly very limited) intuition told me that this sounded quite true, so I came up with the following:
Since $x_n \to 0$, we know that the constituent sequences of real and imaginary parts (henceforth $(r_n)_n$ and $(i_n)_n$ respectively) must both also converge to zero. Since convergence "behaves nicely" under addition multiplication, we have that $(r_n^2)_n$ and $(i_n^2)_n$ must both also converge to zero, as does their sum $(r_n^2 + i_n^2)_n$.
By the comparison test, we know that if we can find a real sequence $(b_n)_n$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \left|x_n\right| \leq b_n$, and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n$ converges, then $x_n$ converges absolutely. Let $b_n$ be the reciprocal of $n^2$ for example; we know that the corresponding series converges. Now note that $\left|x_n\right| = \sqrt{r_n^2 + i_n^2}$; so, if we can find a subsequence indexed by $n_k$ such that $\sqrt{r_{n_k}^2 + i_{n_k}^2} \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$, we have indeed found an absolutely convergent subseries; we can always find such a subsequence since $\sqrt{r_{n_k}^2 + i_{n_k}^2} \leq \frac{1}{k^2} \Leftrightarrow r_{n_k}^2 + i_{n_k}^2 \leq \frac{1}{k^4}$, and the left hand side converges to zero so we can find an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the value is smaller than any given $\varepsilon \gt 0$, in particular $\frac{1}{k^4}$.
Is the proof correct? Is there some part where I gloss over important details or leave out necessary explanations?
Thank you all in advance.

You are making it too complicated. By induction there exist $n_1<n_2<...$ such that $|x_{n_k}|<\frac  1 {2^{k}}$ and we are done.

@geetha290krm thank you for your quick response, but it's not at all obvious to me what the argument there exactly is, could you clarify?

Looks ok, but why overcomplicating by splitting into real and complex part? As $(x_n)$ converges zo zero, you can choose a subsequence $(x'_n)$ s.t. $x'_n < 1/n^2$

$x_n \to 0$ is same as $|x_n|\to 0$ so avoid going to real and imaginary parts.

@Maksim because there is no ordering on $\mathbb{C}$, so I don't quite feel comfortable stating that $x'_n \lt \frac{1}{n^2}$

@geetha290krm ah okay, I see, thank you

Maksim's comment makes no sense.

Maksim just left out some absolute value signs. $|x_n'|<1/n^2$.

Sorry, forgot the $|•|$..
